# drupal 8 path to a specific site

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I'm using dompdf on a drupal 8 site. I need to get the absolute URL for images i want to put inside.

In the method of a controller which generate my pdf, i am able to recover the path:

```
$path = PublicStream::basePath();
// $path returns : sites/default/files 
$getpath = file_create_url($path); 
// $getpath returns : http://localhost/drupal/sites/default/files
```

In fact I don't use default folder and i store everything in the specific site. 
How can i retrieve 'sites/mysite/files' instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very elegant but effective :

```
$host = \Drupal::request()->getSchemeAndHttpHost();
$host .= "/sites/mysite/files";
```